# Is there a stronger word than "incite"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word that conveys the strongest level of inciting someone, pushing someone to do something:

> Their boss *VERB'd* them to work as hard as possible.

The strongest I can think of is *spur*, is there something better?

Comment: Just reading the title, I was ready to answer **coerce**!

Comment: **Instigate** is also a good word to use as a substitute for incite.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can think of *inflame*, *stir up*, *galvanize*, *goad*, or *rouse*.

It can be useful to also read the note reported by the NOAD.

> The best way to start a riot is to incite one, which means to urge or stimulate to action, either in a favorable or an unfavorable sense.
>   If you instigate an action, however, it implies that you are responsible for initiating it and that the purpose is probably a negative or evil one (*the man who instigated the assassination plot*).
>   *Foment* suggests agitation or incitement over an extended period of time (*foment a discussion*; *foment the rebellion that leads to war*). An instigator, in other words, is someone who initiates the idea, while a fomenter is someone who keeps it alive.
>   You can provoke a riot in the same way that you instigate one, but the emphasis here is on spontaneity rather than on conscious design (*her statement provoked an outcry from animal rights activists*).
>   *To arouse* is to awaken a feeling or elicit a response (*my presence in the junkyard aroused suspicion*), or to open people's eyes to a situation (*we attempted to arouse public awareness*).
>   But once you've aroused people, you may have to exhort them, meaning to urge or persuade them, by appealing to their sympathy or conscience, to take constructive action.

Comment: In my little corner of the world, *incite* is what you get when *persuade* is turned up to eleven. It's already strong (except, perhaps, in the lyrics to *Across the Universe*), if more acute than *foment*. It does have that sometimes undesirable connection with *riot*, though, which might make it an inappropriate choice for a simple "let's meet the deadline" pep talk. *Roused* and *galvanized [them] into* both work for me.

Comment: +1 especially for **goad** — this seems the best to me.  It has slightly different connotations from the rest, though — the others mostly suggest the boss made them excited about working hard, but *goad* suggests he persuaded them to work harder than they liked to.

Comment: I particularly like *galvanize*

Answer (score 3):

Exhorted might be the word you seek.

Instructed, impelled, ...

Compelled and forced suggest more than mere words..

Answer (score 2):

My choice would be 'coerced' for that particular sentence.  As in 'Foxconn workers were coerced into working beyond their physical and mental limits.'

Answer (score 0):

I would use **prompt**, or **induce** (in the case where the incitation succeeded).