# Antonym of defuse?

Tags: antonyms

Which is the best antonym for defuse?

Ideally it would be fuse, but I don't think this is an option.
Maybe activate?

Comment: 'Defuse' is usually used metaphorically nowadays. Which sense do you require an antonym for? Please add a linked and attributed dictionary definition for that sense. If the literal one, 'prime' comes close. If the metaphorical, probably a duplicate of [Is there a stronger word than 'incite'](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13450/is-there-a-stronger-word-than-incite/13453#13453)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The sense of defusing a computer program, so it won't do anything, even if called.

Comment: Is that new? Idiomatic? Please give a relevant dictionary definition, as requested, to show it's not just a niche usage. And an example sentence from a reasonable source.

Comment: @Roland - I've never heard "defuse" used in that sense.

Comment: Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info)

Comment: The opposite of "defuse" is perhaps "light a fuse".

Comment: Antonyms can go in many different directions. What in particular are you looking for? Put a fuse on? Light the fuse? Replace a fuse? It would help if you provided a sample sentence that indicated the sense you're seeking. E.g. "We wanted to [rig?] the program so that one button-press deletes all the data."

Answer (score -1):

As concerns physical processes "activate" is not very specific; it means (SOED) "make active, cause to act". For instance, "to activate an alarm" does not mean necessarily "to provide a mechanism or enable a mechanism so that the alarm will work properly" but it means also "to set off the alarm".

For a physical process the term "**enable**" would be proper in certain cases at least and it would always be so  for a strictly logical one, such as in computing machines; it is the antonym of "deactivate", "inhibit" and "defuse"; however, for an alarm, "deactivate" seems a more likely term to use  than "defuse" ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=deactivate+the+alarm%2Cdefuse+the+alarm&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdeactivate%20the%20alarm%3B%2Cc0)), which does not seem to connote the process properly.

Relative to a general process, the following terms can be considered to be antonyms.

- to start the process of
- to trigger the process of
- to initiate the process
- to get the process started
- to get things started
- set  the process in motion